# Use Hölder inequality to show limit of convolution

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx=1$ and let $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ satisfy $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)= L.$  Prove that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) g(x-y)dy=L.
$$
(See  [original reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgay8.jpg))

I’m studying for my qualifications and I don’t know how to start this proof.

Comment: Welcome to mathstack exchange.  It would help if you fully right out the question instead of linking a pdf. For help with formatting, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $R$ such that $\int_{R}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx <\epsilon$ and $|g(t)-L|<\epsilon$ for  $t >R$. Now let $x >2R$. Then $$\left|\int f(y)g(x-y)dy-L\right|$$ $$=\left|\int f(y)[g(x-y)-L]dy\right|\leq \int |f(y)| |g(x-y)-L|dy.$$ 
Note that $\int_{-\infty}^ {x-R} |f(y)| |g(x-y)-L|dy <\epsilon \int |f(y)| dy$ since $y <x-R$ implies $x-y >R$. Next consider $\int_{x-R}^{\infty} |f(y)| |g(x-y)-L|dy$. Let $M$ be such that $|g(t)| \leq M$ almost everywhere. Then $$\int_{x-R}^{\infty} |f(y)| |g(x-y)-L|dy \leq (M+|L|)\int_{x-R}^{\infty} |f(y)| dy$$ $$\leq (M+|L|) \int_R^{\infty} |f(y)| dy <(M+|L|)\epsilon.$$ 
It follows that $|\int f(y)g(x-y)dy-L| <\epsilon \int |f(y)|dy+(M+|L|) \epsilon$. This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:** Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(y)g(x-y)\ dy -L \right| \leq&\ \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(y)||g(x-y)-L|\ dy \\
\leq&\  \int^A_{-\infty}|f(y)||g(x-y)-L|\ dy+ \int^\infty_A |f(y)||g(x-y)-L|\ dy\\
\leq&\ (L+\|g\|_\infty)\int^A_{-\infty}|f(y)|\ dy+ \int^\infty_A |f(y)||g(x-y)-L|\ dy
\end{align}
for any $A$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Following the hint and choose $A=A(\epsilon)$ such that $\int^A_{-\infty}|f|<\epsilon/(2L+2\|g\|_\infty)$ (why is this possible?). Then it follows
\begin{align}
\left|\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(y)g(x-y)\ dy -L \right| \leq&\ \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\int^\infty_A|f(y)||g(x-y)-L|\ dy\\
=& \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \int^\infty_{x-A} |f(x-u)||g(u)-L|\ du\\
\leq& \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\sup_{u \in [x-A, \infty]}|g(u)-L|.
\end{align} 
The rest of the proof should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

[My attempt at the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yopXz.png)

Using Jacky Chong advice, can you see if I did that right?